# Node loses title on submit

Tags: nodes, forms

I am creating a custom module that allows for users to create blog posts that will be private and related to a project. So I created a new content_type called "tasker_blog" that just has a title and body. The user goes to view their projects and clicks a link which takes them to 'tasker_project/%/blog' % being the id of the project. I have the form being displayed correctly but when I submit the form I have two problems, 
  1) the title is lost on submit 
  2) getting this error: EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids().

Here is the code I have written (some non-relevant parts taken out).

```
function tasker_project_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['tasker_project/%/blog'] = array(
        'title' => 'Private Blog Post',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('tasker_project_blog_form',1),
        'access arguments' => array('view tasker projects'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

function tasker_project_blog_form($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'tasker_project') . '/tasker_project.css'); 
    global $user;
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $node = (object) array(
        'uid' => $user->uid,
        'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
        'type' => 'tasker_blog',
        'language' => 'und',
    );
    node_object_prepare($node);

    $form = drupal_get_form('tasker_blog_node_form',$node);
    $form['hidden_project_id'] = array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => arg(1),
    );

    return $form;
}
```

If I submit with nothing else added I get the error I mentioned above. If I add this (using Kint to display variables):

```
function tasker_project_node_validate($node, $form, &$form_state) {
    s($_REQUEST);
    s($form_state['values']);
    die();
}
```

$_REQUEST array output:

```
array (9) (
    'title' => string (4) "test"
    'body' => array (1) (
        'und' => array (1) (
             array (2) (
                'format' => string (13) "filtered_html"
                'value' => string (13) "<p>test</p>
"
            )
        )
    )
    'changed' => string (0) ""
    'form_build_id' => string (48) "form-eKWwyFlBOzi4LsajaAiEZBG7J0uOSI1UDVIhiDomeJE"
    'form_token' => string (43) "N421-IiWecixBJGbxTHGcJAIrd6ZutzAW0LAtVSsrJ4"
    'form_id' => string (24) "tasker_project_blog_form"
    'hidden_project_id' => string (2) "10"
    'additional_settings__active_tab' => string (0) ""
    'op' => string (4) "Save"
)
```

$form_state['values'] array output:

```
array (27) (
    'nid' => NULL
    'vid' => NULL
    'uid' => string (1) "5"
    'created' => integer 1347038959
    'type' => string (11) "tasker_blog"
    'language' => string (3) "und"
    'changed' => string (0) ""
    'title' => string (0) ""
    'additional_settings__active_tab' => string (0) ""
    'revision' => bool FALSE
    'log' => string (0) ""
    'name' => string (10) "ndenlinger"
    'date' => string (0) ""
    'status' => integer 0
    'promote' => integer 0
    'sticky' => integer 0
    'submit' => string (4) "Save"
    'preview' => string (7) "Preview"
    'body' => array (1) (
        'und' => array (1) (
             array (3) (
                'summary' => string (0) ""
                'format' => string (13) "filtered_html"
                'value' => string (13) "<p>test</p>
"
            )
        )
    )
    //...MORE HERE REMOVED SINCE NOT RELEVANT
)
```

So I'm not sure if the two problems are related or not. Once the node is saved I am going to add a row to a custom table that store the nid and the project_id.

Comment: I suggest you print_r or s() $node after    `node_object_prepare($node);`, and before return $form look at $form['title'] ,check it ,maybe problem be in form title field

Comment: Tried that everything looks correct before submitting. I tried setting my own '#validate' and the form_state variable has the title. It is the hook_node_validate() function that is stripping the title for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution in case anyone else ever has this issue:

```
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'tasker_project') . '/tasker_project.css'); 
    global $user;
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $node = (object) array(
        'uid' => $user->uid,
        'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
        'type' => 'tasker_blog',
        'language' => 'und',
    );
    node_object_prepare($node);
    $form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($node);

    $form = drupal_retrieve_form('tasker_blog_node_form', $form_state);
    drupal_prepare_form('tasker_blog_node_form', $form, $form_state);
    $form['hidden_project_id'] = array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => arg(1),
    );
```

I used drupal_retrieve_form and drupal_prepare_form and everything seems to work correctly now. Not sure why drupal_build_form or drupal_get_form don't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Test this

```
function tasker_project_blog_form($form, &$form_state) {
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'tasker_project') . '/tasker_project.css'); 
global $user;
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$node = new stdClass();
$node = (object) array(
    'uid' => $user->uid,
    'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
    'type' => 'tasker_blog',
    'language' => 'und',
);
node_object_prepare($node);

$form = drupal_get_form('tasker_blog_node_form',$node);
$form['hidden_project_id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => arg(1),
);

return $form;
```

}